# Krakenjs routes with i18n URLs

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I want to build a blog with multilang content in Kraken.JS.
How should I build the controller/model/routes to get these URLs:

```
/en-US/article/hello-world
/de-DE/article/hello-world
/it-IT/article/hello-world
```

The slug (hello-world) does not have to be internationalised.
I don't want to copy the controller in files like:

```
controllers/en-US/article/index.js
controllers/de-DE/article/index.js
controllers/it-IT/article/index.js
```

Is there a prettier way to do this with just one controller file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done using a single controller:

Checkout this example for directions on how to accomplish this https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-example-with-i18n#adding-a-hook-to-set-the-locale-on-the-fly

One way to do this might be the following:

```
router.get('/:locale/article/:article_name', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('locale', req.params.locale);
    res.redirect('/article/:article_name');
});
```

There would be only one controller:
`controller/article/index.js`

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this a pretty bad solution? Every request would result in a redirect to a URL without the locale and still rely on a cookie.

Comment: @Nick It is a bad solution.